# Is there a way to check whether ViewPager is currently scrolling between pages?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouch

I am combining ViewPager with onTouch for the same, as it should be possible to both scroll the ViewPager and click it. However, I do not want both triggered, so I am looking for a convenient way to instruct the OnTouch to ignore MotionEvents which triggered a page scroll.
I can of course measure the distance between the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP, but I am wondering whether there is an existing method to help me.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little bit confused. Are you saying that when the `ViewPager` is *scrolled*, you want to only trigger **your** `onTouch` event and ignore the `ViewPager` **callbacks** for `onPageChangeListener` and/or `onClick` ?

Comment: I was looking for a way to distinguish between touch events which lead to scrolling and those which did not. I have a method (based on onTouch) which I apply only for the latter cases. Eventually I just decided to evaluate myself the touchEvent, to identify a non-swipe touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found allows me to identify whether there is a scroll in progress. scrollState has three values defined in ViewPager: SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING and SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING. Now I can check scrollState in the onTouch method and act accordingly.

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    scrollState=state;
}
```